# How to scale histplot data

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot a histogram for data pa.

I wrote a code:

```
pa = np.array(pa)
scale = l ** 2
pa /= scale

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
hist = sns.histplot(pa, kde=True)

plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

The problem is that it whatever I do with pa data (scaling or not) the histogram looks the same.

I want to scale it, so the maximum possible value is 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your usecase you might want to set the `stat` in the histplot function. See the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html).

The default is 'count' but you probably want 'percent' or 'frequency' (or 'proportion')

try:

```py
pa = np.array(pa)
scale = l ** 2
pa /= scale

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
hist = sns.histplot(pa, kde=True, stat='percent')

plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I should read the documentation :D